# A weird text conversation

Tags: steganography, anagram

I just had a very strange SMS conversation with one of my musician friend. Since I need your help, I'll share it with you, hoping that he won't come here...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is a text version of the conversation, where T is my friend and I is (am?) me :

> T: Our most recent call lasted 26 seconds. What is it, a call time for
>   ants?
>
> I: ?? Hey, what's up, bro?
>
> T: Well, tomorrow's your birthday. I might have a gift for you now, but
>   if you disappoint me again, I'll perform a 'bro feint', truly!
>
> I: Sorry, I was in a hurry last time.
>
> T: Whatever. Come join me. Tom is hear. He'll help to settle your club.
>   *here
>
> I: What club are you talking about? I don't own any club Wait, don't even
>   touch my golf clubs
>
> T: (Peter is here too)
>
> I: Peter? Who is Peter?
>
> T: Peter Zoo, the weirdo in our class.
>
> I: What? What is he doing with you?
>
> T: He's the real wolf, man!
>
> I: I don't understand. What is this supposed to mean??
>
> T: Okay, I'll stop toying with you :-). Read our conversation from the
>   start carefully, because I hid something in it which is very relevant
>   to your birthday gift!

Comment: Funny... I was just about to make a similar type of puzzle. Now I'm not sure anymore :P

Comment: @LukasRotter Why? Seems a bad idea?

Comment: @LukasRotter, does that mean you've solved this one already but not posted an answer?

Comment: No, I'm not sure because people would probably accuse me of copying the idea from you (and downvote). @GarethMcCaughan No, my puzzle idea was similar because I also wanted a messenger conversation to be the puzzle. It's not really a duplicate since it isn't an anagram / steganography puzzle.

Comment: I can't speak for anyone else, but if I saw two successive puzzles with similar framing but fundamentally different actual puzzle content I wouldn't see that as reflecting badly on the second. I'd think "oh, do we have a tradition developing here?".

Comment: though personally I have no particular desire to see puzzles whose content is presented in three large images when it could exactly equivalently be shown in a short block of text :-).

Comment: Iphone 4? Not very up to date :P

Comment: Is the tag [anagram] a deliberate clue, a guess, or just some random tag which is might or might not be relevant?

Comment: @Matsmath I'm pretty sure IAmInPLS is the actual creator of the puzzle and the [anagram] tag is genuinely informative.

Comment: Well, this is certainly a weird text conversation. (1) Appropriate letters are capitalized (and others aren't). (2) There is (appropriate) punctuation in (only) the appropriate places (except for a few sentences that have no punctuation at the end). (3) There are no absurd, obscure abbreviations. WTF? WPAYGF? (What planet are you guys from?)

Comment: "*one of my musician friend*" - is any knowledge of music (meaning any whatsoever) required to solve this puzzle?

Comment: @randal'thor Well spotted :-) !

Comment: Peter zoo might be Jupiter. There may be some connection with some rock band. Also, bro feint doesn't yield any sane result in online anagram solvers. 26 second may have some connection with letters of alphabet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your side of the conversation contains some

> anagrams of the names of American heavy metal bands, as suggested by Petter:
>
>  a call time = Metallica
>  Tom is hear = Aerosmith
>  bro feint truly = Iron Butterfly (M Oehm)
>  settle yöur club = Blue Öyster Cult (M Oehm)
>  Peter Zoo = Zoetrope (Petter)
>  the real wolf = Leatherwolf (Arka Karmakar)
>
>  Wikipedia describes Iron Butterfly as an American psychedelic rock band, but lists heavy metal among its genres, so it seems that heavy metal is relevant, and Petter got the complete relevant connection here.

Comment: @ArkaKarmakar: Well done, but I still don't see the Peter Zoo/Jupiter connection.

Comment: Well done everybody. I don't know how to attribute the tick now... Maybe we wait for @RosieF to complete the answer?

Comment: If finding the band's name is the only step in this puzzle, that makes it good to very very little extend. @IAmInPLS The question now could be community wiki.

Comment: @ArkaKarmakar You mean that my puzzle is not good? That's mean :(. Well it lasted almost three days, with almost no hints given from me.

Comment: @IAmInPLS I am not saying all or even most of your puzzles are bad, but don't like two or three. I loved the security guard or calculator puzzle. But I don't like this because there's ought to be something deep per than simply finding out the anagrammed rock band words. Also, how does it fits with the context - only two/three anagrams were sufficient to give the idea that it is something about rock bands. An well thought multiple layered puzzle, like the security guard, is much better than this in my humble opinion .

Comment: @ArkaKarmakar I don't force anyone to like any of my puzzles... I believe that this one, though quite simple, can be enjoyable...

Comment: @RosieF Congrats! After giving the answer to my friend, he handed me tickets to see a concert of Slayer! Yay!

Comment: PS: here's the list I used : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_heavy_metal_bands